How enumerate threads running in a specific desktop?
Suppose that a process calls the SetThreadDesktop() API to capture the screen of a specific desktop.
Is it possible to identify this thread inside of the desktop and know the caller process?
If yes, could you provide a code example for it?

Edition:
With reference to Remy's answer i have this following code, but GetLastError() to GetThreadDesktop() is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.
function GetProcessNameByID(ProcessID: DWORD): string;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  ProcessName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ProcessID);
  if hProcess <> 0 then
  begin
    if GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, 0, ProcessName, MAX_PATH) > 0 then
      Result := ProcessName;
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;
 
function GetUserObjectName(hUserObject: THandle): string;
var
  Count: DWORD;
begin
  GetUserObjectInformation(hUserObject, UOI_NAME, PChar(Result), 0, Count);
  SetLength(Result, Count + 1);
 
  if GetUserObjectInformation(hUserObject, UOI_NAME, PChar(Result), Count, Count) then
    StrResetLength(Result)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
 
function SetUserObjectAllAccess(hUserObject: THandle): Boolean;
var
  Sd: PSecurity_Descriptor;
  Si: Security_Information;
begin
  Sd := PSecurity_Descriptor(LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH));
  InitializeSecurityDescriptor(Sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(Sd, True, nil, False);
 
  Si := DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
  Result := SetUserObjectSecurity(hUserObject, Si, Sd);
 
  LocalFree(HLOCAL(Sd));
end;
 
function GetThreadsList(PID: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  SnapProcHandle: THandle;
  NextProc: Boolean;
  TThreadEntry: TThreadEntry32;
  SessionID: Cardinal;
  DeskObj: HDESK;
begin
  SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  Result := (SnapProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  if Result then
  try
    TThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TThreadEntry);
    NextProc := Thread32First(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);
    while NextProc do
    begin
      //if TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then
      if GetProcessNameByID(TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID) = 'Project2.exe' then
        begin
        Writeln('Thread ID:        ' + {IntToHex(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID, 8))}IntToStr(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID));
        Writeln('Process ID:       ' + Inttostr(GetProcessIdOfThread(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID)));
        ProcessIdToSessionId(TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID, SessionID);
        Writeln('Session ID:       ' + IntToStr(SessionID));
        Writeln('Window Station:   ' + GetUserObjectName(GetProcessWindowStation));
        Writeln('Process Name:     ' + GetProcessNameByID(TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID));
        DeskObj := GetThreadDesktop(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID);
        SetUserObjectAllAccess(DeskObj);
        Writeln('Desktop Name:     ' + GetUserObjectName(DeskObj));
        Writeln('Base Priority     ' + inttostr(TThreadEntry.tpBasePri));
        Writeln('');
      end;
      NextProc := Thread32Next(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);
  end;
end;
 


There is not a specific API to enumerate threads in a desktop. You will have to enumerate all available threads using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() and Thread32(First|Next)() (see Enumerating threads in Windows), and then filter them using GetThreadDesktop().

I had used all these apis, but when have a thread running in a different desktop (not WinSta0\Default) , not is possible get desktop name. Why this not working? See, exists a thread in "Project2.exe" running in a new desktop every Sleep(10); but GetThreadDesktop() always fails.

"but GetThreadDesktop() always fails" - what does GetLastError() report when it fails?

5 (0x5) - ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Desktops and Processes belong to a Window Station. AFAIK, you can't access Desktops across Window Station boundaries, so you might need to have your app call SetProcessWindowStation() on itself for the target Window Status before enumerating. On a side note - I see some issues in your GetThreadsList() code: 1) you don't need GetProcessIdOfThread() since you have th32OwnerProcessID; 2) GetProcessWindowStation() gets the Window Station of the calling process, but you probably want the Window Station of th32OwnerProcessID instead.

Could edit your answer with fixed code please?
